# Retaining variable values from one execution to another

Tags: c

Hi
Consider I have two programs `a.c` and `b.c`. The program `b.c` is executed a number of times from `a.c` using `execve()`. I wish to retain the values of the variables and data structures defined in `b.c` from one execution to another. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `a.c` set up a chunk of [shared memory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_shm.h.html) and then `b.c` could store its state data in that shared memory. Of course `b.c` would have to depend on `a.c` to manage its state but that shouldn't be a problem if `b.c` exists only to be called by `a.c`.

Alternatively, you could store all the state data in a single `struct` and use [`fwrite`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) and [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) to store and retrieve the state. Or you could use [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) to make this approach easier. You'd have to be careful if some of your state involved a pointer though. You don't have to use a single struct for this approach but it would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

have `b.c` load and save its state from and to a file.

Comment: d think of it but it is not actually very efficient.Thanks.